# Browse files and want to upload on Server

Tags: ios, swift, uidocumentbrowserviewcontroller

I am using UIDocumentBrowserViewController to browse the file and getting the URL of the selected file from UIDocumentBrowserViewControllerDelegate method.

```
 func documentBrowser(_ controller: UIDocumentBrowserViewController, didPickDocumentsAt documentURLs: [URL]) {
        guard let fileUrl = documentURLs.first else { return }
         do {
              let fileData = try Data(contentsOf: fileUrl)
          } catch {
              print(error.localizedDescription)
          }
 }
```

Now I have to upload this file to our app server, so I am trying to convert it into Data but it's not converting. Getting an error 'The file "File name" couldn’t be opened because there is no such file'.

Comment: Does it get past your `guard`?  Does it print anything?

Comment: @PhillipMills Yeah I am able to get the URL but not able to convert it into Data

Answer (score 1):

I am using UIDocumentBrowserViewController but it's not working while I am trying to import the document always getting the issue so I use UIDocumentPickerViewController   and its working fine for me.